# Is there an `update migration` (ala South) option for django.db.migrations?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-migrations

In South there was a nice command:

`schemamigration frontend --auto --update`

Which would take the most recent (unapplied) migration and update it to match whatever change was in the model.  It was really handy during dev.

Does the new django migrations module that was introduced in 1.7 have an option like that?  Looking at the docs I suspect not: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations

Comment: IIRC, it's on Andrew's (author of South and the new migrations) list of features to be implemented (though that doesn't mean it'll be there anytime soon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in django >=1.7 there is nothing like this, but you also dont need it actually.

if you make changes in your models, you can either edit the latest migration file if the changes are only defaul values, choices etc, and thats it or just `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

I personally find this way much more clear and easy to work with.

Comment: The --option was very useful if you just wanted to add something you forgot in the previous migration. It didn't just update the previous migration, it also reverted it if it was already applied.